# How to redirect HTTPS traffic to HTTP with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I'm working on the next subdomain: http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com

My domain does not have HTTPS, so if I go to https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com, the browser tells me: *This site can not be reached*.

I want to do this: If someone tries to access my domain via https, it must be redirected to http.

I see that there are a thousand sites that tell me how to do it, **but nothing works for me!**. Https never redirects to http. And the site http falls).
All examples speak of domains. My case is different, because I work on a subdomain. This will make the difference?

I use these lines in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

On the third line, I changed alternately by each of these options without success:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://misubdominio.midominio.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Can you help please?

Comment: "This site can not be reached" could mean that your server isn't listening on port 443 which handles HTTPS. If that's the case that would explain why your .htaccess doesn't work for you. I suggest you talk to your admin to clarify.

Comment: First even if you get the **correct** rewrite rules, you need a valid cert for each subdomain or the redirect will still **not** work. Or you can buy a wildcard cert to cover them all, either way you need a valid cert or your users are going to get a warning screen with that scary message that it's not trusted. SSL handshake happens before redirect. Also don't just guess using rewrites you find. Actually try to understand it. None of those rewrites will help you do what you want.

Comment: You need a valid SSL cert to redirect away from HTTPS, and at that point it might make more sense to just deploy HTTPS site wide.